# SparseBooleanArray and 2 arraylists, item not removed from arraylist

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a listview from which I remove selected items, I am doing this through a SparseBooleanArray.

However when I remove the **selected items**, I also want them removed from that position from 2 other arraylists (**trackedItems, dateWatchList**) but in the **dateWatchList** arraylist always 1 item it **not** removed.

I already checked several threads but I cannot get this right.

Would be great if someone can help.

Code piece:

```
...
SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

   for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {

       if (checkedItems.get(i)) {
       // This item is checked and can be removed
       trackedItems.remove(i);
       dateWatchList.remove(i); // 1 item always remains and is NOT removed?
       adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
       }
   }

   checkedItems.clear();
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, for anyone who has the same problem, here is my working code:

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

   for (int i = checkedItems.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
       String selecteditem = adapter.getItem(checkedItems.keyAt(i));
       String currentName = trackedItems.get(checkedItems.keyAt(i));
       long currentDate = dateWatchList.get(checkedItems.keyAt(i));

            if (checkedItems.get(checkedItems.keyAt(i))) {
                adapter.remove(selecteditem);
                trackedItems.remove(currentName);
                dateWatchList.remove(currentDate);
            }
    }
    checkedItems.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```